# Thread code is not stable with blocking loop

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm trying to get a threaded process working, but it seems to get more unstable with multiple executions.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to determine what the cause is?  One big difference, though, is that I'm using a blocking loop on the multiple executions instead of letting it pass through asynchronously like I have it coded to do as well.

This is the wait loop code I'm using (most obvious place to start).  I need to have it this way, so TMainObject can process any events off of messages FThreadProcess sends.

```
procedure TMainObject.WaitForCompletion;
  begin
    repeat
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    until WaitForSingleObject(FThreadProcess.Handle, 20) = WAIT_OBJECT_0;
  end;
```

When I take each item and process it asynchronously in separate runs, I have no problems whatsoever.  Does anyone have any other ideas on things to check?  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the right way to do that loop is with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` because that allows it to block and be woked whenever there are messages in the queue rather than using a timeout. As for your question, utterly impossible to answer with this information.

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is that I really don't know where to begin looking, since I'm new to coding major processes in threads.  I've hit my head off and on for a few times in trying to solve why the process works at times and hangs up at other times.  FWIW, it's downloading files using WinHTTP so that might help in a direction to look.

Comment: I'd love to help, but there's not enough info to advise. General advice would be to strip the program down to the bare minimum and gradually build it back up.

Comment: What if the thread exits when application is processing messages?

Comment: @Sertac That's no problem surely. The wait will then succeed because the handle hasn't been closed yet (unless of course this is a FreeOnTerminate job)

Comment: @David - it's stated in `pHandles` parameter description: `If one of these handles is closed while the wait is still pending, the function's behavior is undefined.`, so if you free your thread at `Application.ProcessMessages;` processing no one can guarantee the result.

Comment: @David - Surely!.. If it is though, an invalid handle would cause an infinite loop, perhaps an AV if lucky..

Comment: @deamon_x Who said anything about closing handles? When a thread exists, the handles to that thread don't suddenly become invalid. Nobody closes them for you! You have to close them.

Comment: Basically if you want accurate help rather than guesses, you need to show us some more code.

Comment: @daemon - I don't understand what the documentation mean with that, the wait will fail or succeed. Honest question, what do you think as an undefined behavior?

Comment: @David - ok, sorry I missed your comment `unless it's a FreeOnTerminate job`, Sertac - I think they mean that it may succeed even if the handle is already closed. I mean if the thread exits at `Application.ProcessMessages;` and has FreeOnTerminate = True then the `WaitForSingleObject` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` may return "anything" because the handle is closed, what in the current code can cause very long (or infinite) loop.

Comment: @David: When TThread shuts down, the destructor closes its handle.  An externally obtained handle is invalid after that point.

Comment: @Mason Clearly is a ProcessMessages destroys the TThread instance then its game over. But I see no evidence that is happening. I am very familiar with what happens in TThread.Destroy.

Comment: @daemon - Nice undefined behavior. Not sure if that scenario can cause it though. I wonder if it might mean closing the handle while the thread is executing, but who would do that? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Actually one of the guesses was pretty good.  I did "FreeOnTerminate := true" along with this waiting loop and received occasional AVs, so it's likely this is the cause.  I'm in the process of reworking the code.  That given, I'll check back if the problem persists.  Thanks!

Comment: My advice is never to use `FreeOnTerminate`. If you use this feature you can't talk to the thread reliably, although it can talk to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going only on the information available here, limited as it is, I'd have to say that Sertac Akyuz's comment is probably on the right track.  If the thread finishes while you're processing messages, and the thread has `FreeOnTerminate` set, then your `WaitForSingleObject` call will fail in any number of different ways.

To do this right, start the thread off, and then have the last thing it does be to post a message back to whichever form started it off, and put a message handler on there that kicks off the "work is complete" code.

This is yet another example of why explicit calls to `Application.ProcessMessages` should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Agree, this is the safe way to go.

Comment: +1 for getting the thread to post a message when it is done rather than polling. Polling blows chunks.

Comment: Hard to say if WaitForSingleObject will fail if the handle is already closed when the `function's behavior is undefined` in this state but also +1 for posting message.

Comment: Using a "Completed" message handler is what I used, but there are two problems I haven't quite solved that I've encountered.  Not solving these necessitated the wait loop.  1. How would this work if you were to call it in a command-line situation, where the program would continue and terminate? 2. How would you do this with complex logic & multiple calls to the thread containing object?

Comment: @Glenn: Those are both complicated questions, requiring more detail in the asking and more space than the character limit here allows to answer them well.  Try making two new questions, and you're likely to get some good answers on here.